# Plot a graph with a factor to be ordered based on the alphabetic order of another variable using tidyverse

Tags: r, string, ggplot2, factors

consider the data set below which has `Nbr` variable which is a factor that has unordered levels. The order should follow the alphabetical order of the `char` vector in the data set. I navigated the web to look for a similar case where you want to plot the graph ordering a factor based on another vector, and I found many that use numerical vectors but not string vectors and not in the alphabetical order as in this question. I didn't find a solution in the factor section of the book "R for Data Science" (aka [R4DS](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html#modifying-factor-levels)).

**MWE**

```
df <- structure(list(Vis = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
), class = "factor"), char = c("Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", 
"Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", "Fro", 
"Fro", "Fro", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", 
"Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", "Gae", 
"Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", 
"Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Ada", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", 
"Bal", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", "Bal", 
"Bal", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", 
"Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Ebe", "Dei", 
"Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Dei", 
"Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Dei", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", 
"Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb", "Geb"
), Nbr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("5", 
"6", "1", "2", "4", "3", "7"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
104L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code**

```
ggplot() +
  geom_raster(aes(Vis, Nbr), data = df)
```

**Plot**

[image]

```
levels(df$Nbr)
[1] "5" "6" "1" "2" "4" "3" "7"
```

**Question**

How to order the y-axix (Nbr) factor based on the alphabetical order of the `char` vector using tidyverse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)
dfplot <- df %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(char))

ggplot() +
  geom_raster(aes(Vis, forcats::fct_inorder(Nbr)), data = dfplot)
```

**Output**

[image]

**Hints to the solution**

there is a huge potential of combining the `dplyr::arrange()` tool with the `forcats::fct_inorder()` to get whatever ordered levels you like. The former will do the sorting/arrangement/ordering of the **factor** for you based on other variable(s) **in** the dataframe but the latter will preserve that arranged **order** inside your `ggplot()` graph. May be that's why it is called **[fct]_[in][order]()**.

**Reference**

Package [forcats](https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_inorder.html) by Hadley Wickham.